# Asus Router (RT-AC51U) blocking websites

Tags: router, wireless-router

I try to use trello on my laptop over wlan with my new Asus RT-AC51U Router but it is blocking some resources. There for I am unable to use trello and some other sites over this connection. If I use the lan directly from my modem, it works fine. So it has to be the router.

Now I looked into the Administration Interface of the router, but I can't find any active blocking mechanism. Can anyone help me find out where to disable these - I would say, default filters?

Thats how it looks in the browser after login
[image]

Then after I refresh.
[image]

Thats what I see in the chromium error console.
[image]

#### Update 1

I just noticed, that I no longer can use the imgur service, which is used to upload images on stackexchange over the new router :/

#### Update 2

Finaly I think it is the `https://trello.com/1/Members/me?channels=true&notifications=all&notifications_limit=5&notifications_display=true&notification_memberCreator_fields=fullName%2Cinitials%2CmemberType%2Cusername%2CavatarHash%2Cbio%2CbioData%2Cconfirmed%2Cproducts%2Curl&organizations=all&organization_paid_account=true&organization_fields=name%2CdisplayName&paid_account=true&savedSearches=true` link, which is not responding. But I don't see on which port this was requestet. How can I find it out?

#### Update 3

Things get anoying right now, here I have encountered another error, which seams to be a different one?
[image]

#### Update 4

I have read, that maybe the MUT is to high. But I only can set the MUT if I switch from *dynamic IP* to *PPoE*. Could it be that?

Comment: what error did you get? are the problematic sites related with https (green https, SSL).

Comment: https is _green_.

Comment: i was saying if the blocked sites that you can't access use https, is the problem related only to https sites? What error you get when you open the site on browser?

Comment: for eg. trello it is blocking a lot of https://d78fikflryjgj.cloudfront.net

Comment: I can't open the link, is an image? If the message generated is from you router than go with the solution below

Comment: The blocked resources come over the cloudfront cdn which is provided over https. And some how it is blocked from the router without any active filters ...

Comment: so do you open any site on https or not? if yes second attempt, it may be a DNS problem, try to configure 8.8.8.8 as DNS server directly on your PC and see if you can access this sites

Comment: why would it be a dns problem? If i go over my router it is blocked if i don't it is not. And yes trello comes over https.

Comment: maybe the dns that you router use cant resolve hosts like `asdf.cloudfront.net`. Anyway the problem definitely should be on the ports opened on router firewall. as you see the JavaScript errors are connected to specific ports 24178; 3426; 750 etc. Can you disable completely the router firewall?

Comment: Did you try the different DNS or not?

Comment: @Dave yes i did

Comment: @emirjonb I will look again, but I did not found something yet ... but thanks for pointing the port thing out! :)

Comment: @emirjonb there is nothing activated in the firewall, but there is no setting that lets me deactivate the firewall in generall.

Comment: This is probably obvious step, but i have forgotten before: but did u try factory resetting the router?

Answer (score 3):

this is liekely due not exactly to the MTU but rather to the MSS (maximum segment size) which derives from the MTU.

When your computer connect to a website, it initiate the TCP connection with a handshake. During this handshake the MSS is negotiated.

Your computer is connected to your router with ethernet or wifi that permit a given MSS, 1460
However the router is connected to the internet trough PPPoE for example that has a lower MTU and so a lower MSS, of 1452.

When your computer communicate with the web site it announce a MSS of 1460. So the web site send his packet with this MSS. Since it's bigger than the MSS your internet connection can handle, it fails.

Many systems have way to handle this but some simply doesn't and will fail at establish the connections.

I don't know if there's setting on your router to handle this.

You could artificially reduce the MTU on your computer so it use a lower MSS :

```
Open a command line window as an Administrator (ie. right click on All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt and select Run as administrator) ...
Type the command netsh and wait for prompt
Type the command interface and wait for prompt
Type the command ipv4 and wait for prompt
Type the command set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1492 store=persistent
```

1492 should do the trick (usually MSS = MTU-40), if not, lower it a little bit until it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my Asus Router was blocking only one website (our company's website). Changing the DNS settings from auto to Google Public DNS resolved the issue immediately. This was definitely a router issue because if a computer was plugged directly into the modem, the site worked. No computers connected to the network could load the site until the DNS change was made. Also tried factory reset unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the Firewall on your router

In the manual for your router, section 4.6 is about the following topics:

Firewall - General
Firewall - URL filter
Firewall - Keyword filter
Firewall - Network Services Filter

I suspect the last one is what you need. At least, you can disable the Firewall totally, test again. This will indicate if the issue is the firewall or not.

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/RT-AC51U/E9422_RT-AC51U_manual.pdf#page=1&zoom=auto,-301,598

Comment: there is nothing enabled in the firewall. no filter mechanism active which i can influence.